# plot a stacked bar chart with a double y axis in matlab

Tags: matlab, charts, plot

Hi I am trying to plot a stacked bar chart with a double y axis in matlab. I can plot a stacked or a double y by themselves but not together!

What I have so far is

```
Industry = [436.8 508 388 351 273]';
Domestic = [778.05 762 777 632 517]';
Road_Transport = [1092 921 1061 1041 702]';


  figure;
 bar(1:5,[Industry Domestic Road_Transport],0.5,'stack');
```

Now I want to add a 6th column to each of the above, called "Total"

```
  Total = [1958 3466 4808]';
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB doesn't let you plot bar graphs with only 1 column of data. So you trick it by padding it with 0s.

My code

```
fun = @(x,y) bar(x, y, 0.5, 'stack')
plotyy(1:5,[Industry Domestic Road_Transport],5:6,[zeros(3,1) Total]', fun)
```

The first bar graph goes from 1 to 5 and the second from 5 to 6 but you don't see the 5th column in the `Total` graph.